# Calculating a running sum of subtask cost amounts

Tags: ms-project

How can a Summary task reflect a running sum of subtask input amounts?
[image: subtasks to sum]

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking - are you asking how to build a formula to count the Document Numbers?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are trying to sum the custom currency field you have named AMT $ ?

1. Right click on the column heading to show the shortcut menu.
2. Select **Custom Fields** to open the Custom Fields dialog.
3. From the **Calculation for task and group summary rows** section, select **Rollup** and then select **Sum** from the list.

[image]